# Raspberry pi B+ broken piece

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've just opened and broken a piece on my new Raspberry Pi B+.  It's the small piece in the linked image.  I bumped it, tried to bend it back and then it broke off.

Is this reparable, and if so how?  Soldering something so small is a bit scary.

The damaged piece is in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLHye.jpg

Comment: I recommend moving this to the [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site - this question is off topic on this site, but would not be off topic there.

Comment: Yes, it's repairable and yes, it will require soldering. And BTW this question is entirely off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is meant exclusively for *programming* questions.

Answer (score 1):

It is the power LED. It is of no consequence other than you will not know if the power is on or not, but otherwise it should function fine.  They probably told you the same thing over on the raspberry pi site.